# SQLite DB created/not visible on device (Moto G3)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to create an SQLite database on my testing device Moto G3. Neither I am getting any error nor its writing any data. **Just to mention, I don't have SDCard**.

Here is the Database Helper Class:

```
    package com.apptree.dingdong.database;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


    public class DatabaseUserHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Dingdong.db";
        private static final String TABLE_USER_DATA = "user_data";

        // Contacts Table Columns names
        private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        private static final String KEY_EMAIL_ID = "email";
        private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

        public DatabaseUserHandler(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            Log.d("Snapper"," DatabaseUserHandler created ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER_DATA + " ("
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_EMAIL_ID + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_NAME + " TEXT" + ");";

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            Log.d("Snapper"," DatabaseUserHandler onCreate called "+db.getPath().toString());
            Log.d("Snapper"," DatabaseUserHandler query "+CREATE_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER_DATA);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public void addUser(UserData user) {
            Log.d("Snapper"," User created ");
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Log.d("Snapper"," DatabaseUserHandler db version "+db.getVersion());

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_NAME, user.getName());
            values.put(KEY_EMAIL_ID, user.getEmail());
            // Inserting Row
            db.insert(TABLE_USER_DATA, null, values);
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

Here I am initialising the class in an activity:

[image]

When I log the path where the database is created. I get following path which does not exists (Checked in Android Devie monitor).

> data/user/0/com.d.dingdong/databases/Dingdong.db

What I am missing?

Comment: Not an expert and don't have a reference handy but I would focus on the CREATE_TABLE string.  Spaces in the right place, etc.  (Maybe there should be a space after the commas?)

Comment: Thanks, buddy @Gary99. Seems you are correct. Followed a tutorial. The author has messed up with query.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text.

Comment: Hey @Yunnosch Really sorry but I am not able to add code. There was some error. So had to add an image.

Comment: You **did** add code, there is a code-formatted part right above your picture link. This makes it unlikely that you cannot add code... If formatting is a problem, see the help on formatting, e.g. markdown. Formatting help is to the right of the field you edit your question in "Formatting help".

Comment: What happens when you try to write the data? Some error? Can you read the data in your app?

Comment: I can read data. But not able to see the database. strange problem. @CL.